# Is there a way for someone to read my contract?

Tags: solidity, web3js

I made a Contract, "AA" then deployed it. I think, people can execute my Contract's function, but they can't read whole contents in my Contract. Can people know the details of my contract? (e.g. using web3...)

Comment: Everything in the blockchain is public. Someone dedicated can reverse engineer the contract execution, there are some tools for contract decompilation from the bytecode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone, who wants to read your code, could use the following method to get the bytecode: [web3.eth.getCode(address [, defaultBlock] [, callback])](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.9/web3-eth.html?highlight=getCode#getcode)

The method returns the bytecode. All they need to do know, is to reverse it :)

So yea, it is possible.

Comment: How can people change bytecode to source code?

Comment: Here is an example: https://ethervm.io/decompile